# Make divs of same class the size of biggest one

Tags: html, css

so I got some divs, something like this:

```
<div class="personal-events-list">
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something</div>
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something else</div>
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something more</div>
</div>
```

and I want them to have the same size (assuming that what makes sense is the size of the biggest one), something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxgzK.jpg

and currently I have something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZmKt.jpg

Currently I have CSS with "width: fit-content" but that just makes them all different sizes. The only real solution I came up with was making them all a fixed size, like "width: 300px" but that would make some bigger/smaller names look kinda funky... is there a way to do what I want?

Thanks alot for your time!

**Edit 1: Added CSS**

```
.specific-event {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.specific-event:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current CSS as well?

Comment: Did you try to use word-wrap property? [Visit it](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_word-wrap)

Comment: @John done! check it out!

Comment: @Emre i tried it but didn't get it to work, any suggestions on how to use it?

Comment: @GuilhermeMoreira see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `width: fit-content` to your `.personal-events-list` instead of `.specific-event`

Like this:

```css
.specific-event {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.specific-event:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  color: white;
}

.personal-events-list {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="personal-events-list">
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something</div>
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something else</div>
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something more</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS word-wrap property.

```css
.specific-event {
  width: fit-content;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 8px;
  /* You should add these lines. */
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width:300px;
}

.specific-event:hover {
  background-color: #9c9c9c;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="personal-events-list">
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something</div>
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something else, and some things.</div>
    <div class="specific-event black-font">Something more. For example, I am writing the long sentence.</div>
</div>
```